# Fractional part of a certain random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

The following claim is made (without proof) in a book I am reading:

> Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, and let $k\geq 2$ be an integer. Define $V=kU-\lfloor kU\rfloor$. Then $V$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and is independent of $U$.

While I found it plausible that $V$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, it seems suspicious to me that $V$ would be independent of $U$. So I considered a simple example when $k=2$. If $U\leq \frac{1}{3}$ then $V=2U$, so on this event $V\leq \frac{1}{4}$ if and only if $U\leq \frac{1}{8}$. Therefore
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big(U\leq \frac{1}{3},V\leq \frac{1}{4}\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(V\leq \frac{1}{4}\mid U\leq \frac{1}{3}\Big)\mathbb{P}\Big(U\leq \frac{1}{3}\Big)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}\Big(U\leq \frac{1}{8}\mid U\leq \frac{1}{3}\Big)\mathbb{P}\Big(U\leq \frac{1}{3}\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(U\leq \frac{1}{8}\Big)=\frac{1}{8} $$
which is not equal to $\frac{1}{12}$.

Am I missing something silly, or is the claim incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following simulation, the claim of independence seems incorrect.

```
u = runif(10^5)
v = 2*u - floor(2*u)
cor(u,v)
## 0.502127
```

A histogram of $V$ seems consistent with $V \sim Unif(0,1),$ as claimed.
But correlation is pretty clear from a plot of $V$ against $U.$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice to know I'm not crazy.

Comment: What is the context of this problem: Drill exercise? Connections to CS application?

Comment: It was in a book on simulation. The idea was to avoid having to generate a second uniform random variable.